# undefined variables (date_revision_start, hour_start, hour_end)

Tags: laravel

I have a problem, when I encode my fields and that I confirm my form. I have an error message:

`undefined variables (date_revision_start, hour_start, hour_end)`

I think that, I have to declare these 3 variables?

```
$date_revision_start = '?????';
$hour_start = '?????';
$hour_end = '?????';
```

Here is my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'date_seance' => 'required',
            'hour_start' => 'required',
            'hour_end' => 'required',
            'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
            'fk_former' => 'required',
            'fk_student' => 'required',
            'fk_typeseance' => 'required'


        ]);

      /*$date_revision_start = 
       $hour_start = 
       $hour_end = */

        $start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_revision_start . ' ' . $hour_start);
        $stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_revision_start . ' ' . $hour_end);

        //dd($start_time, $stop_time);
        etc...



        $data = $request->all();
        $data['start_time'] = $start_time;
        $data['stop_time'] = $stop_time;
        Training::create($data);
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('success', 'Add');


    }
```

Comment: yea they have to exist before you can get a value from them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't yet defined these variables.  If they are coming in through your form, just set a block to create them before pushing into your Carbon method.

So, before the Carbon call, something like:

```
 $hour_start = $request->input('hour_start');
 $hour_end = $request->input('hour_end');
 $date_revision_start  = $request->input('date_revision_start');
```

And so forth.  Obviously, you'll need to have these fields on your form so they can be processed.

Comment: side note, the recommended way of getting inputs from the request is `input` not `get`

Comment: Heh, today it is... we've got way too many `get`s to go back and change do to some frivolous change in flavor of the day.  Not worth the time or cost.  And then there's the standards to follow vs. Laravel standards... which the guys debate every time we get into change process lol.  Just not worth it ;)

Comment: there is a reason laravel created the `input` method and doesn't use the `get` method from the symfony base class ... it isn't a flavor of the week ... the 2 methods can have different results do to priorty of how sources are checked ... this is why the docs dont show using the `get` method ... when you call `all` that is calling `input` ... there is a chance the data returned from `all` won't match the input you request via `get` because of the difference between `input` and `get`

Comment: this has been the recommended method to use since 5.0 at the least ... even in 4.0 `Input::get(...)` was calling `$request->input(...)` ... this isn't a new thing at all

Comment: The reasons you state are solid.  But we've used the get method from symfony projects, and carried those over to Laravel when it came around, following standards of the day.  Likely should do a find/replace on these, but with working production code, this seldom turns out flawlessly, nor is seldom worth the cost.  Since it is a simple change (word for word), probably time to look into it. Let me start with replacement in this answer!

Comment: yea just wanted you to know there is actually a reason for it ... but i understand many things can be preference and preferences have changed in the community, so i get that, just this particular thing can have a functional difference

Comment: obviously it hasn't been an issue in your projects so you probably dont need to change anything ... this illustrates the difference in priority: https://gist.github.com/lagbox/fb65adb4331a61bc4a0714b62ecac678  ... should only be an issue if you get `all()`, do something with that data, then later get a single input via `get()` where it could potentially be different than what it was from `all()`

Comment: No, hasn't been an issue to date... but your demo is *very* interesting to me.  I am certain there will be cases where we could do precisely this.  Really appreciate the time to show.  Running a business, there is no greater bane than having to refactor based on superfluous changes to a codebase or package.  This shows that this could have real consequence.  Thanks again.

Comment: https://asklagbox.com/blog/illuminate-request  goes into some things to watch out for with Request and has some links to github where these issues are described

Comment: @Watercayman: I have an error message? `Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing`
"d-m-Y H: s"
"18:00"

Comment: Your format is likely incorrect to match the form.  Take a look at what is coming back from the form (`dd($request->input('date_revision_start')`) and match to the format coming in.  IE tweak  `d-m-Y H: s` to match what you are sending from the form.  Most likely the `date_revision_start` is a DATE, and the `H: s` will not work for that format.  Try that date field with just `d-m-Y` or similar

Answer (score 1):

You saw right,declare these three. With what I see of your code you can declare them like this

```
 $date_revision_start  = $request->get('date_seance');
 $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
 $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
```